# Which conjectures are proved for sofic groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, sofic-groups

Which conjectures about groups are resolved in case of sofic groups?

I know two examples:

1. Kaplansky's direct finiteness conjecture (proved by Gabor Elek).
2. Some versions of Ornstein's isomorphism theorem (proved by Lewis Bowen).

What other examples are there?

Comment: Which conjectures about groups do you _know_?

Comment: I would add to the list Gottschalk's conjecture (in a very general version) by Gromov (who defined sofic groups)